# Interaction of static methods inherited from an abstract class and generic types (see description)

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, abstract-class, static-methods

I have an abstract class Chainable which contains a dummy static method as follows:

```
public abstract class Chainable implements Comparable<Chainable> 
{
    public static ArrayList<Chainable> create_index(ArrayList<Chainable> chain)
    {
        return new ArrayList<Chainable>();
    }
}
```

This static method is overridden in its inheritors, i.e. in the Note class:

```
public class Note extends Chainable
{
    public static ArrayList<Chainable> create_index(ArrayList<Chainable> chain)
    {
        return sort(quantize(chain));
    }
}
```

Now, I have a class Chain which takes a Chainable parameter T and contains an ArrayList of Chainables. I want to write a create_index method for chain as follows, that will call the specific method defined on the Chainable T that is passed in as a paremeter:

```
public class Chain<T extends Chainable> 
{
    private ArrayList<T> list;

    public ArrayList<Chainable> create_index()
    {
        return T.create_index(list);
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the error "create_index (java.util.ArrayList) in Chainable cannot be applied to (java.util.ArrayList)."  I do not understand this, because I have specified that T is a Chainable in the class definition of Chain. Could you tell me what's going on here?

Comment: Generics just don't support this - and you can't override static methods.

Comment: OK - what is a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Normal inheritance - that may require a parallel inheritance hierarchy, or it may not.